# iOS when i use the framework in my project, it can build success ,but the method didn't work.the invoke do nothing at all

Tags: ios, frameworks

I built a dynamic framework, and I added it to my sample project. It builds and runs well. However, when the sample call the method in framework, it did nothing, and I did not get any error or exception.

```
+(id)getInstance{
printf("000000");
NSLog(@"000000");
@synchronized(self){  //
    NSLog(@"11111");
    printf("11111");
    if (!client) {
        NSLog(@"2222");
        [BlueManager getInstance];
       client =  [[self alloc] init]; //
        NSLog(@"333");
    }
}
NSLog(@"client point:%@",client);
//printf("444444");
return client;}
```

Here's the sample:

```
 NSLog(@"ssssssss");
_client = [Client getInstance];

_client.initDelegate = self;
[_client initSDK:1 promotion:@"1000" key:@"2_3DAF68786000000000000000000" language:@"en"];   // [client ini]
```

The message "ssssssss" can output on the window, but the function `getInstance` does not output, and the `_client` is nil, when it executes to the line of code `_client.initDelegate = self`;

This framework worked well few days ago, but I can't remember what have I changed in the configuration of the Xcode, I have dealt with this problem for two days!

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in `getInstance`?

Comment: It's not clear what that is supposed to do.  Where is `client`, in `BlueManager`?  Why do you ignore the return of `[BlueManager getInstance]`?

Comment: can not execute into getInstance.

Comment: @trojanfoe  nope ,i have return the instance. the message in getInstance "000000" does not output. It means that , this function does not be called.